# Thinktecture claims authorization workflow. How does it work?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-model

I have installed the **Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Core** package.

Suppose I've registered my custom implementation of `AuthorizationManager` in **web.config** file.

```
public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager {
    public override Boolean CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context) {
        // authorization implementation
    }
}
```

There are a permissions defined in the application db for user roles. So that **`User`** might have **`Read`** permission for **`Blogs`** and **`Arts`** resources if it is in a **`BasicUser`** role.

The workflow as I see it:

1. at login you make a *db query* to fetch all **action-resources pairs** from *all assigned roles* for the **authenticated user**
2. then you gotta add **claims** (based on the db query result) to the **identity**
3. **`ClaimsAuthorizationAttribute`** makes a call to the **`ClaimsAuthorizationManager`**
4. **`ClaimsAuthorizationManager`** internally checks the authentication cookie with claims from the step 2

Am I right?

Or am I supposed to do a database permission lookup inside the `CheckAccess` method? Will this work on a per-request basis?

Howcome I transform/attach the db-fecthed set of action-resources into identity claims?

Comment: Regardless of Thinktecture I like the Idea of grouping claims by roles in this sample project : https://github.com/trailmax/ClaimsAuthorisation/tree/master/ClaimsAuth/Controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the checkaccess method you are not supposed to lookup database. You are supposed to check whether claims Inside AuthorizationContext allows the user to access action/ressources. Claims are supposed to be filled during Authentication.

At login, you can fetch roles from you database and add them to the claims then the claims can be stored in the cookie or in session to avoid fetching them on each request. Cookie or Session storage of claims is handled natively (and securely) using the right configuration.

Comment: Can you please illustrate that? What types of claims should I add? I think the relation between **`Action`** and the corresponding **`Resources`** isn't separable. And I just have read a thread about unsuccessful deserialization of custom complex claims. If a single claim must be a key-(primitive)value to support deserialization then how do I properly add them to the claims identity?

Comment: You can fill claims from a custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager.